# Variavel dinâmica + inclusão campo form

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá.

O escopo é assim..
Tenho um titular que pode ter n dependentes.
A pessoa relacionada na venda faz upload de arquivos de titular e dependente.
Salvo uma pasta com o número do CPF do titular no servidor e, lá dentro, sigo a estrutura de salvar o CPF dos dependentes com os documentos.

Criei uma classe específica para adicionar o campo "documentos" no formulário e ele pode incluir, no máximo, 3 campos para esse upload;

Para o titular, eu tenho a função pronta, contudo, na parte de dependentes, tenho um problema..

```
$(".adiciona").click(function(event)
    {
        var nId = event.target.id;
        var sId = nId.split("_");
        var id  = sId[1];

        var MaxInputs       = 2; 
        var InputsWrapper   = $("#InputsWrapper_"+id); 
        var AddButton       = $("#AddMoreFileBox_"+id);

        var x = InputsWrapper.length; 
        var FieldCount = 1; 

        if(x <= MaxInputs) 
        {
            FieldCount++; 


            $(InputsWrapper).append('<div><input type="file" name="arquivoDep_'+id+'[]" id="field_'+id+'_'+ FieldCount +'"/> <a href="#" class="removeclass">Remove</a></div>');

            x++; 

            $("#AddMoreFileId_"+id).show();

            $('AddMoreFileBox_'+_id).html("Adiciona Documento");

            if(x == 3) {
                $(AddMoreFileBox_+_id).hide();
                $("#lineBreak").html("<br>");
            }
        }
        return false;


    });
```

Os campos são adicionados nas DIVs certas, mas, nenhum dos contadores funciona e não consigo fazer um controle de quantos documentos está sendo enviado.

https://jsfiddle.net/9w7maLe1/

Alguma ajuda de como resolver?

Desde já, grato.